# How to get the list of available variables from a StringTemplate template

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I'd like to obtain the list of variables from a template to request them from a UI application.

Let's say I have a template like

```
This is some template called $templateName$ with the description $templateDescription$
```

I was wondering if there is any way to get the list of available variables/parameters, in this case:

- templateName
- templateDescription

In List or Array